# Inequalities Problem : Cancelling out the variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic, functional-inequalities

$\frac{(x+4)}{(x^2-9)} - \frac{2}{(x+3)} < \frac{4x}{(3x-x^2)}$

Below is my solution apprach for this solution :-

$\frac{x+4}{x^2-9} - \frac{2}{x+3} < \frac{4x}{3x-x^2}
\\ \Rightarrow \frac{x+4}{x^2-9} - \frac{2}{x+3} < \frac{4}{3-x} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{x+4}{(x+3)(x-3)} - \frac{2}{x+3} < \frac{-4}{x-3} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{x+4}{x+3} - \frac{2(x-3)}{x+3} < -4 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{10-x}{x+3} <-4 \\ \Rightarrow x<-\frac{22}{3}
$

But this is not the correct answer. Can someone please tell me what am I missing here?

Answer : $x \in (-\infty,-7.33) \cup (-3,3)-\{0\}$

Comment: How did you get $7$ in the denominator? Pls check.

Comment: Sorry..my mistake ...i have fixed that....but still this is not the answer set..

Answer (score 1):

You solved as if you were solving an equation for $x$, but from the looks of the solution, the question would have said " find the range of $x$ "
$$\frac{(x+4)}{(x^2-9)} - \frac{2}{(x+3)} \lt \frac{4x}{(3x-x^2)}$$
$ x \in \{ -\infty \} $

$$\frac{ (x+4)(x+3)-2(x^2-9)}{(x+3)(x^2-9) } \lt \frac{4x}{(3x-x^2)}$$
$$(3x-x^2) \big( (x+4)(x+3)-2(x^2-9) \big) \lt 4x(x+3)(x^2-9) $$
$$x(3-x)(x+4)(x+3) -2x(3-x)(x+3)(x-3)\lt 4x(x+3)^2(x-3)$$
$$-x(x-3)(x+4)(x+3) +2x(x-3)^2(x+3) \lt 4x(x+3)^2(x-3)$$
$$ (x-3)(x+3) \big[ -x(x+4) +2x(x-3) \lt 4x(x+3) \big] $$
$$ (x-3)(x+3)(\dots \dots )$$
$ x \in \{ 3, -3 \}$
$$ -x^2-4x+2x^2-6x \lt 4x^2+12x $$
$$ 0 \lt 3x^2+22x$$
$$ 0 \lt x(3x+22)$$
$ x \in \{ 0, -\frac{22}{3} \}$

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply by $x+3$, or $x-3$, it matters whether that is positive or negative.  If it is negative, you have to change greater-than to less-than.
Break it into three separate cases: $x\lt-3,-3\lt x\lt3,3\lt x$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you figured out these 3 separate cases "Break it into three separate cases: x<−3,−3<x<3,3<x." ?

Comment: Thr two factors you multiply by are $x+3$ and $x-3$.  The sign of $x+3$ matters  so break at $x=-3$, and the sign of $x-3$ matters, so break at $x=3$

Answer (score 0):

When you are to find all possible values of $x$ meeting the inequality, you should rather expand as is.

$\displaystyle \small \frac{x+4}{x^2-9} - \frac{2}{x+3} \lt \frac{4x}{3x-x^2}$ simplifies to,

$\displaystyle \small \frac{x+4-2x+6}{x^2-9} \lt \frac{4x}{3x-x^2}$

$\displaystyle  \small \mathbf {\frac{10-x}{x^2-9} \lt \frac{4}{3-x}} \ $ when $\mathbf {x \ne 0}$

i) When $x \gt 10$, both LHS and RHS are negative. So the inequality becomes

$\displaystyle \small \frac{x-10}{x^2-9} \gt \frac{4}{x-3} \implies 3x \lt -22 $ which is contradictory.

ii) When $3 \lt x \lt 10$, RHS is negative and LHS is positive and hence there are no solutions.

iii) When $-3 \lt x \lt 3$, RHS is positive and LHS is negative so inequality holds.

iv) when $x \lt -3$, both LHS and RHS are positive.

$\displaystyle \small \frac{10-x}{(-x-3)} \lt 4 \implies x \lt -\frac{22}{3} \ \big[ $ note $(-x-3)$ is positive as $\displaystyle \small x \lt -3 \big] $.

Comment: Upon solving your equation, I got the range for x as $x>3$ and $-22/3<x<0 $but this does not seem to match with the answer that I have mentioned in the question. Can you please expand your solution a little bit more?

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my working